# Make HTML Button Visible in Email but Invisible in Browser

Tags: html, css, email

Some background: I have a pre-built system where I can define HTML to notify a user of an event in the system (record created, status change, etc.)  The same notification is sent both as an email and store in the system.  In other words, the same HTML notification is shown in both the browser and the email.  The system is rigid and provides no way for me to define different HTML for the email vs. what is shown in the browser.

Is there a way show a link/button only in the email and not in the browser?  I'm looking for a CSS or HTML way to read the context of where it's being viewed then conditionally display the button.  I do not want to use javascript or a script tag for fear of an email client marking my email as dangerous/spam.

Here's my button for what it's worth:

```
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td align="center" style="-webkit-border-radius: 3px; -moz-border-radius: 3px; border-radius: 3px;" bgcolor="#dedede">
      <a id="GoToLink" href="https://stackoverflow.com" target="_blank" style="font-size: 16px; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color: #000000; text-decoration: none; text-decoration: none; -webkit-border-radius: 3px; -moz-border-radius: 3px; border-radius: 3px; padding: 12px 18px; border: 1px solid #959595; display: inline-block;">Go to incident</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: email clients would probably just ignore the javascript part, so if it's intended only for your website it should work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that is quite possible with HTML/CSS.

Can send an email and then manipulate/remove button with JavaScript? If you have that option of course.

If I understand you store your content as string or something? Then you can also try to replace button tag with blank before sending an email?